# Iterating a python object and filtering it

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, urllib2

The JSON notation I get from the Webservice:

```json
{
"students": [
    {
        "studentId": 127292,
        "studentName": "Mary"
    },
    {
        "studentId": 15555,
        "studentName": "Joe"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to iterate the JSON object and get student id based on the student name.

For example, if I have to get `studentId` of `'Joe'`, how we can process that in Python?

```
try:
    req = urllib2.Request(url, headers = header)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    jsonObject = json.load(response)

except Exception as e:
    print e
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a "JSON object" for Python. There is JSON notation, and there are Python objects. Have a look at the Python ``dict`` and ``list`` types.

Answer (score 1):

i suggest to remap your data to a dictionary where you can lookup your students by name:

```
data = {
"students": [
    {
        "studentId": 127292,            
        "studentName": "Mary"            
    },
    {
        "studentId": 15555,            
        "studentName": "Joe"            
    }
  ]
}

lookup = {student["studentName"]: student["studentId"] for student in data["students"]}
id_of_joe = lookup.get("Joe", "No student named Joe")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can iterate over the JSON object to get the student ID in each field

```
studentIds = []
for obj in jsonObject:
    sID = obj['studentId']
    studentIds.append(sID)
```